# Is there a microformat for menu (nav)?

Tags: navigation, microformats

Is there a microformat for menu (nav)?

I didn't find one here: http://microformats.org/wiki/Main_Page

Comment: The best way i have found it is to use Schema. https://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no specific microformat for menu/nav, but the XOXO (Open XHTML Outlines) specification provides an open outline format that can be used for lists that conform to the HTML list module. XOXO is incredibly easy to implement; I've been using it as a default class for certain lists for a long time now. More/references listed below:

[XOXO Specification](http://microformats.org/wiki/xoxo)
[XOXO Profile](http://microformats.org/wiki/xoxo-profile)
[HTML List Module](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-modularization/abstract_modules.html#s_listmodule)

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn’t.

Of course [`h-item`](http://microformats.org/wiki/h-item) could be used for almost anything, including each navigation item, but there’s probably no point in doing this.

For certain links in the navigation, a link type could be used (some are defined in the Microformats wiki, and most are [listed there](http://microformats.org/wiki/existing-rel-values) at least), including:

- [`home`](http://microformats.org/wiki/rel-home) for the link to the homepage
- [`payment`](http://microformats.org/wiki/rel-payment) for the link to a page asking for e.g. donations